A problem to compile the Quantum ESPRESSO with external libraries
I try to compile the Quantum ESPRESSO (QE) using the following external libraries: fftw-3.3.10, lapack-3.12.0, hdf5-1.14.4-2, libxc-6.2.2. To compile QE, I use the standard commands:
./configure --prefix=/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/build
make -j2 all
make install

Before starting a compilation of QE I compile the libraries from sources. To make QE understandable where the libraries are I use the following system variables:
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/_/progs/qe/lapack-3.12.0/build/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/_/progs/qe/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/build/include $CPPFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/build/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/_/progs/qe/libxc-6.2.2/build/include $CPPFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/_/progs/qe/libxc-6.2.2/build/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/_/progs/qe/hdf5-1.14.4-2/build/include $CPPFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/_/progs/qe/hdf5-1.14.4-2/build/lib $LDFLAGS"

It is good — QE finds these variables at configuring. But at the second command make -j2 all, the compilation process turns out a fatal error, here is a bite of the console log:
I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include  -c fftw_interfaces.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include  -c fft_scalar.FFTW3.f90
fft_scalar.FFTW3.f90:41:2:

   41 | 
      |  1          
Fatal Error: fftw3.f03: No such a file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [../../make.inc:16: fft_scalar.FFTW3.o] Error 1
make[2]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib/src"
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: fftx] Error 1
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib"
make: *** [Makefile:203: libfft] Error 1
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c print_mem.f90

What can I do in this situation to complete the compilation process successfully?
Addition I

Compilers used for compilation:

C — gcc;
C++ — g++;
Fortran — gfortran.

Operation system: Linux Mint 21.3
Here is the whole log of the compilation:
me@linux:~/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/build
directory QEHeat/src : ok okkokCI : ok
directory ACFDT/src : not present in /home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/install
directory KCW/PP : okk
all dependencies updated successfully
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking ARCH... x86_64
checking setting AR... ... ar
checking setting ARFLAGS... ... ruv
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether the Fortran compiler works... yes
checking for Fortran compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking for Fortran flag to compile .f90 files... none
checking for mpiifx... no
checking for mpiifort... no
checking for mpif90... mpif90
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
checking whether mpif90 accepts -g... yes
checking version of mpif90... gfortran 11.4
setting F90... gfortran
setting MPIF90... mpif90
checking for cc... cc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
setting CC... cc
setting CFLAGS... -O3
using F90... gfortran
setting FFLAGS... -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch
setting F90FLAGS... $(FFLAGS) -cpp
setting FFLAGS_NOOPT... -O0 -g
setting CPP... cpp
setting CPPFLAGS... -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/hdf5-1.14.4-2/build/include -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/libxc-6.2.2/build/include -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/build/include -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/lapack-3.12.0/build/include
setting LD... mpif90
setting LDFLAGS... -L/home/me/_/progs/qe/hdf5-1.14.4-2/build/lib -L/home/me/_/progs/qe/libxc-6.2.2/build/lib -L/home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/build/lib -L/home/me/_/progs/qe/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether Fortran files must be preprocessed... no
checking for library containing dgemm... no
MKL not found
in /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64: checking for library containing dgemm... no
MKL not found
checking for library containing dgemm... no
in /usr/local/lib: checking for library containing dgemm... no
checking for library containing dgemm... -lblas
setting BLAS_LIBS... -lblas
checking for library containing dspev... -llapack
in /usr/local/lib: checking for library containing dspev... -llapack
checking FFT... checking for library containing dfftw_execute_dft... -lfftw3
 -lfftw3 
checking MASS... 
checking for library containing mpi_init... none required
checking for library containing pdgemr2d... no
checking for library containing pdgemr2d... no
checking for library containing pdgemr2d... no
checking for library containing pdgemr2d... no
checking for library containing pdgemr2d... no
checking ELPA... 
checking for Environ... not used
checking if legacy plugins are enabled ...  no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for wget... wget -O
setting WGET... wget -O
checking for git... git
setting DFLAGS... -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI
setting IFLAGS... -I. -I$(TOPDIR)/include
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating install/make_lapack.inc
config.status: creating include/configure.h
config.status: creating make.inc
config.status: creating configure.msg
config.status: creating install/make_wannier90.inc
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ESPRESSO can take advantage of several optimized numerical libraries
(essl, fftw, mkl...).  This configure script attempts to find them,
but may fail if they have been installed in non-standard locations.
If a required library is not found, the local copy will be compiled.

The following libraries have been found:
  BLAS_LIBS= -lblas 
  LAPACK_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -llapack  -lblas 
  FFT_LIBS= -lfftw3 
  
  

Please check if this is what you expect.

If any libraries are missing, you may specify a list of directories
to search and retry, as follows:
  ./configure LIBDIRS="list of directories, separated by spaces"

Parallel environment detected successfully.\
Configured for compilation of parallel executables.

For more info, read the ESPRESSO User's Guide (Doc/users-guide.tex).
--------------------------------------------------------------------
configure: success
me@linux:~/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1$ make -j 2 all
test -d bin || mkdir bin
( cd UtilXlib ; make TLDEPS= all || exit 1 )
cd install ; make -f extlibs_makefile libcuda
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/install"
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/UtilXlib"
cd /home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src; \
ln -fs /home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//make.inc ../; \
make all; \
touch /home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//install/libcuda_devxlib # do not download and configure again
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c parallel_include.f90
make[2]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib/src"
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_auxfunc_mod.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_fbuff.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c nvtx_wrapper.f90
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c cptimer.c
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c copy.c
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c c_mkdir.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c device_helper.f90
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c eval_infix.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c find_free_unit.f90
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c fletcher32.c
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c md5.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_memcpy_mod.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c md5_from_file.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_memcpy.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c memstat.c
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c memusage.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c mem_counter.f90
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include   -c ptrace.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c util_param.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c clib_wrappers.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c clocks_handler.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c mp.f90
mp.f90:2783:19:

 2783 |    CALL MPI_Irecv( recvbuf, size(recvbuf), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
      |                   1
......
 2827 |    CALL MPI_Irecv( recvbuf, size(recvbuf), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                   2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:2788:19:

 2788 |    CALL MPI_Isend( sendbuf, size(sendbuf), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
      |                   1
......
 2832 |    CALL MPI_Isend( sendbuf, size(sendbuf), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                   2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:2579:30:

 2579 |    CALL MPI_Sendrecv_replace( buf, SIZE(buf), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
      |                              1
......
 2613 |    CALL MPI_Sendrecv_replace( buf, SIZE(buf), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                              2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:2401:22:

 2401 |    CALL MPI_ALLTOALL( sndbuf, nsiz, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                      1
......
 2437 |    CALL MPI_ALLTOALL( sndbuf, nsiz, MPI_INTEGER, &
      |                      2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/INTEGER(4)).
mp.f90:2322:29:

 2322 |                              alldata, recvcount, displs, my_element_type, gid, ierr )
      |                             1
......
 2346 |                              alldata, recvcount, displs, my_element_type, gid, ierr )
      |                             2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).
mp.f90:2293:29:

 2290 |            CALL MPI_GATHERV( MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, &
      |                             2
......
 2293 |            CALL MPI_GATHERV( alldata(1,displs(myid+1)+1), recvcount(myid+1), my_column_type, &
      |                             1
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/INTEGER(4)).
mp.f90:2252:26:

 2252 |         CALL MPI_GATHERV( mydata, nrecv( myid + 1 ), MPI_INTEGER, &
      |                          1
......
 2290 |            CALL MPI_GATHERV( MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, &
      |                             2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-2)
mp.f90:2155:26:

 2155 |         CALL MPI_GATHERV( mydata, recvcount( myid + 1 ), MPI_INTEGER, &
      |                          1
......
 2290 |            CALL MPI_GATHERV( MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, &
      |                             2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-1)
mp.f90:1974:40:

 1974 |         CALL parallel_min_real( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                        1
......
 1986 |         CALL parallel_min_real( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                        2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1952:43:

 1952 |         CALL parallel_min_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           1
......
 1963 |         CALL parallel_min_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1929:40:

 1929 |         CALL parallel_max_real( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                        1
......
 1941 |         CALL parallel_max_real( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                        2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1900:43:

 1900 |         CALL parallel_max_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           1
......
 1916 |         CALL parallel_max_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1870:39:

 1870 |         CALL reduce_base_real( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                       1
......
 1886 |         CALL reduce_base_real( 2 * msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:1732:43:

 1732 |         CALL reduce_base_real( 2 * msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           1
......
 1886 |         CALL reduce_base_real( 2 * msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                           2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1680:42:

 1680 |         CALL reduce_base_real_to( msglen, msg, res, group, root )
      |                                          1
......
 1793 |         CALL reduce_base_real_to( 2 * msglen, msg, res, gid, -1 )
      |                                              2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:1438:42:

 1438 |         CALL reduce_base_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                          1
......
 1528 |         CALL reduce_base_integer( msglen, msg, gid, -1 )
      |                                          2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:1342:28:

 1342 |              CALL MPI_SEND( msg_sour, SIZE(msg_sour), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dest, ip, group, ierr)
      |                            1
......
 1389 |              CALL MPI_SEND( msg_sour, SIZE(msg_sour), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, dest, ip, group, ierr)
      |                            2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:1346:28:

 1346 |              CALL MPI_RECV( msg_dest, SIZE(msg_dest), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, sour, ip, group, istatus, IERR )
      |                            1
......
 1393 |              CALL MPI_RECV( msg_dest, SIZE(msg_dest), MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, sour, ip, group, istatus, IERR )
      |                            2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:726:28:

  726 |         CALL bcast_logical( msg, msglen, source, gid )
      |                            1
......
  758 |         CALL bcast_logical( msg, msglen, source, gid )
      |                            2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:634:25:

  634 |         CALL bcast_real( msg, 2 * msglen, source, gid )
      |                         1
......
  711 |         CALL bcast_real( msg, 2 * msglen, source, gid )
      |                         2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:620:25:

  620 |         CALL bcast_real( msg, msglen, source, gid )
      |                         1
......
  711 |         CALL bcast_real( msg, 2 * msglen, source, gid )
      |                         2
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/COMPLEX(8)).
mp.f90:443:28:

  443 |         CALL bcast_integer( msg, msglen, source, group )
      |                            1
......
  817 |         CALL bcast_integer( imsg, msglen, source, group )
      |                            2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mp.f90:191:24:

  191 |         CALL MPI_GATHER(mydata, 1, MPI_INTEGER, alldata, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, group, IERR)
      |                        1
......
  215 |         CALL MPI_GATHER(mydata, msglen, MPI_INTEGER, alldata, msglen, MPI_INTEGER, root, group, IERR)
      |                        2
Warning: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (rank-1 and scalar)
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_auxfunc.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
cc -O3 -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include   -c timer.c
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c timer_mod.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c device_fbuff_mod.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//include  -c deviceXlib_mod.f90
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib//external/devxlib/src’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
ar ruv libdevXlib.a deviceXlib_mod.o device_memcpy.o device_memcpy_mod.o device_auxfunc.o device_auxfunc_mod.o device_fbuff.o device_fbuff_mod.o timer.o timer_mod.o
ar: the "u" modifier is ignored since the default is "D" (see "U")
ar: libdevXlib.a is created
a - deviceXlib_mod.o
a - device_memcpy.o
a - device_memcpy_mod.o
a - device_auxfunc.o
a - device_auxfunc_mod.o
a - device_fbuff.o
a - device_fbuff_mod.o
a - timer.o
a - timer_mod.o
ranlib libdevXlib.a
make[2]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/external/devxlib/src"
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/install"
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c data_buffer.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c fletcher32_mod.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c mp_base.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c mp_base_gpu.f90
( cd FFTXlib ; make TLDEPS= all || exit 1 )
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib"
( cd src ; make all || exit 1 )
make[2]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib/src"
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include  -c fft_param.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include  -c fftw_interfaces.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include  -c fft_scalar.FFTW3.f90
fft_scalar.FFTW3.f90:41:2:

   41 | 
      |  1          
Fatal Error: fftw3.f03: No such a file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [../../make.inc:16: fft_scalar.FFTW3.o] Error 1
make[2]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib/src"
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: fftx] Error 1
make[1]: exit from the directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/FFTXlib"
make: *** [Makefile:203: libfft] Error 1
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c print_mem.f90
make: *** Waiting for completion of tasks…
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c thread_util.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c divide.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c error_handler.f90
mp_base.f90:142:20:

   90 |            CALL MPI_BCAST( array, n, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, root, gid, ierr )
      |                           2
......
  142 |      CALL MPI_BCAST(array, n, MPI_INTEGER, root, gid, ierr)
      |                    1
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(8)).
mp_base.f90:601:22:

  385 |         CALL MPI_REDUCE( ps(1+(n-1)*maxb), buff, maxb, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, root, comm, info )
      |                         2
......
  601 |       CALL MPI_REDUCE(ps(1 + (n - 1) * maxb), buff, maxb, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, root, comm, info)
      |                      1
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(8)).
mp_base.f90:604:25:

  388 |         CALL MPI_ALLREDUCE( ps(1+(n-1)*maxb), buff, maxb, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, comm, info )
      |                            2
......
  604 |       CALL MPI_ALLREDUCE(ps(1 + (n - 1) * maxb), buff, maxb, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, comm, info)
      |                         1
Warning: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(8)).
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c mp_bands_util.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c export_gstart_2_solvers.f90
mpif90 -O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW3 -D__MPI  -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//external/devxlib/src -I. -I/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1//include -I. -c set_mpi_comm_4_solvers.f90
ar ruv libutil.a clib_wrappers.o clocks_handler.o cptimer.o copy.o c_mkdir.o device_helper.o divide.o data_buffer.o eval_infix.o error_handler.o export_gstart_2_solvers.o find_free_unit.o fletcher32_mod.o fletcher32.o md5.o md5_from_file.o memstat.o memusage.o mem_counter.o mp.o mp_base.o mp_base_gpu.o mp_bands_util.o parallel_include.o print_mem.o ptrace.o set_mpi_comm_4_solvers.o util_param.o thread_util.o nvtx_wrapper.o       
ar: the "u" modifier is ignored since the default is "D" (see "U")
ar: libutil.a is created
a - clib_wrappers.o
a - clocks_handler.o
a - cptimer.o
a - copy.o
a - c_mkdir.o
a - device_helper.o
a - divide.o
a - data_buffer.o
a - eval_infix.o
a - error_handler.o
a - export_gstart_2_solvers.o
a - find_free_unit.o
a - fletcher32_mod.o
a - fletcher32.o
a - md5.o
a - md5_from_file.o
a - memstat.o
a - memusage.o
a - mem_counter.o
a - mp.o
a - mp_base.o
a - mp_base_gpu.o
a - mp_bands_util.o
a - parallel_include.o
a - print_mem.o
a - ptrace.o
a - set_mpi_comm_4_solvers.o
a - util_param.o
a - thread_util.o
a - nvtx_wrapper.o
ranlib libutil.a    
make[1]: exit from directory "/home/me/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1/UtilXlib"
me@linux:~/_/progs/qe/qe-7.3.1$

Addition II

I've excluded the fftw-3.3.10 library as external from the $CPPFLAGS and $LDFLAGS, and the compilation gets successful. Thus the problem narrows down.
Addition III


For complilation fftw-3.3.10 I went through the instrunction described in the README under the heading "INSTALLATION FROM AN OFFICIAL RELEASE" where only the three commands must be applied (standard way).
The file fftw3.f03 I see in the directory /home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/api and /home/me/_/progs/qe/fftw-3.3.10/build/include.


If it's not too long to fit in the post, please include the whole log for the compilation. This will give us more info about what went wrong (for example, whether it was just this one file that failed or if others failed in a similar way). What Fortran/C compilers are you trying to use?

@Tyberius Thanks! Sure.

Since you have narrowed it down to fftw linking/compilation, how have you compiled fftw? You mention having compiled it from source beforehand. I notice there is big warning on FFTW3 Github README that many of the files are automatically generated and that the source there is incomplete. Did you go through the instructions here? Do you see fftw3.f03 anywhere in the installation directory?

@Tyberius I made an Addition III in the post.
